# Java: client socket does not read the second line and remains open after the terminator line

Tags: java, sockets, client

Having read tens of examples online, I am still stuck with the problem.

I am sending a message from my client in Java to a server in C++. After receiving the hand-shake message, the server sends back the following data:

"0000:1111:2222:3333:4444

END_CONNECT_DATA"

As soon as the last line (terminator) is read by the client, it should close the connection.

This is how I do it:

```
    Socket socket = null;

    String  terminator = "END_CONNECT_DATA";

    try
    {
        int serverPort = 7767;
        String ip = "192.168.1.10";
        String messageOut = "HAND-SHAKE MESSAGE";

        socket = new Socket(ip, serverPort);

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream());

        //Send message
        output.writeBytes(messageOut);

        //Read Response
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String s = "";

        while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("CHECK !!!");
            System.out.println(s);
            sb.append(s);

            if(s.contains(terminator))
            {
                System.out.println("CHECK TERMINATOR");
                break;
            }
        }

        socket.close();

        String data = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("FULL DATA:\n");
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sock:"+e.getMessage());
    }

    catch (EOFException e)
    {
        System.out.println("EOF:"+e.getMessage()); 
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IO:"+e.getMessage());
    }

    finally 
    {
        if(socket!=null)
        {
            try 
            {
                socket.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get back from the server is only the first line. The cursor goes to the next line and continues blinking. The socket connection is not closed. Looks like the client is not reading the terminator (the second line of the message) at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: At least bother explaining the reason for down voting.

Comment: The loop exits and close the socket when it fails to read the next line. How was the message sent from your server? As 2 separate messages or a single message with a new line in between?

Comment: One single message with the terminator starting on a new line. I know, it fails to read the second line. But why?

Comment: And by the way, the loop does not seem to exit, because I do not see "FULL DATA" printed on my console.

Comment: Since you're reading in line by line, your terminator will need to be followed by a new line character. In that way, the `BufferedReader` will pick up that the second line has terminated, hence, reading the result.

Comment: Hm. Not sure if this is the case. Do you think I would not be able to read just one line sent by a server?

Comment: Right now your input looks like this `0000:1111:2222:3333:4444\nEND_CONNECT_DATA` where the `BufferedReader` is expecting `0000:1111:2222:3333:4444\nEND_CONNECT_DATA\n`. As mentioned, the loop is not exiting because `END_CONNECT_DATA` is in the buffer, waiting for `\n` to register that line has terminated. You could update the server side to end the message with `\r` or `\n` for a quick resolution.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I will try what you suggested in your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), the loop fails to read in the second line as it's not terminated with `\r` or `\n`. Therefore, returning only the result up till then, which is the first line as described.

You'll need to either add in a `\r` or `\n` right after the terminator or use `BufferedReader.read()` instead and check manually or adopt another strategy to read in the message

Comment: Thank you. I will try `BufferedReader.read()` and report if it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly the case!

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers

Comment: Well. Kind of. I use now `while((value = br.read()) != -1)  { char c = (char)value;}` Looks like it still does not exit the loop. Although it does read the terminator.

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn If you got the line terminator, which BTW remains impossible, you should have exited the read loop at that point. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: I do not have a line terminator in the second line. How do I exit the loop after the message has been read in this case?

Comment: OK. For now, I did it with `sb.append(c); if(sb.toString().contains(terminator)) { break; }`. May be there is a better approach...

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the peer is neither sending a line terminator after the last line nor closing the socket. *Ergo* using `readLine()` to read those messages is not correct. If you can adjust the peer, do so.

Comment: The server does send the second line (terminator). I checked it using a client that I wrote for my iOS devices. I want to avoid changing anything on the server side. If not using `readLine()`, how else could I read the whole message from the server?

Comment: It is absolutely not possible that the peer sent a second line terminator given your problem statement. In any case you have accepted another answer that says it doesn't. `readLine()` isn't the only read method in the JDK.

Comment: Sorry, I confused the line terminator with the word terminator used to indicate that the socket must be closed. My fault.